# About the usage of jQuery onclick bind function in the book [You Don’t Know JS: this & Object Prototypes]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem about the detail of bind function. Here is the example:

```
// Parent class
function Widget(width, height) {
  this.width = width || 50;
  this.height = height || 50;
  this.$elem = null;
}

Widget.prototype.render = function($where) {
  if (this.$elem) {
    this.$elem.css({
      width: this.width + "px",
      height: this.height + "px"
    }).appendTo($where);
  }
};

// Child class
function Button(width, height, label) {
  // "super" constructor call
  Widget.call(this, width, height);
  this.label = label || "Default";
  this.$elem = $("<button>").text(this.label);
}

// make `Button` "inherit" from `Widget`
Button.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
// override base "inherited" `render(..)`
Button.prototype.render = function($where) {
  // "super" call
  Widget.prototype.render.call(this, $where);
  this.$elem.click(this.onClick.bind(this));
};

Button.prototype.onClick = function(evt) {
  console.log("Button '" + this.label + "' clicked!");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $body = $(document.body);
  var btn1 = new Button(125, 30, "Hello");
  var btn2 = new Button(150, 40, "World");
  btn1.render($body);
  btn2.render($body);
});
```

The upper code snippet is from the book [You Don’t Know JS: this & Object Prototypes], and the problem is the code :

```
this.$elem.click(this.onClick.bind(this));
```

Since `$elem` is assigned to button, but why `this.onClick.bind(this)` can be 
bind to the click event of Button.prototype.onClick. This syntax make me 
confused, is there any one know the exact reason?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach an event listener with jQuery, like so: `this.$elem.click(...);`, jQuery automatically binds the element (in this case, the `button` element) to the callback function's context. In other words, jQuery makes the `this` keyword in an event handler to reference the element that fired the event.

In your case, the code of the `onClick` function (in `Button.prototype`), expects the `this` to reference the current instance of the `Button` object, and not the HTML element. Thus, you have to explicitly bind the correct object to the callback function's context using `bind` - `this.onClick.bind(this)`.

**TL;DR**

If you wouldn't have used `bind`, the `this` keyword in the callback function would refernce the clicked `button` element instead of the `Button` object instance.